# Command added to visudo still is failing on permissions?

Tags: sudo, root

My sudo file has two commands in it right now that are allowed to run without logging in as root.

It looks like this:

```
user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/user/prog1.py
user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/user/prog2.py
```

The `prog1.py` file runs fine without password needed.  The `prog2.py` file fails on permissions denied?

The first program is only accessing a file to read that is root protected.  The second program is creating a symlink and removing a root-protected file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
from random import choice
from subprocess import Popen


def back_drop_change():
    link = "/usr/share/slim/themes/default/background.jpg"
    os.remove(link) # this is the line that returns permission denied
    image_selection = list()
    for di, _, fi in os.walk("/home/user/pictures/apod"):
        for f in fi:
            image_selection.append(di + "/" + f)
    bck_img = choice(image_selection)
    Popen(["ln", "-s", bck_img, link])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    back_drop_change()
```

I try adding `/usr/bin/rm /usr/share/slim/themes/default/background.jpg` to the visudo file but, it still fails?

EDIT:

Some extra information --
`sudo -l` returns:

```
Matching Defaults entries for user on this host:
    env_reset, editor="/usr/bin/vim -p -X", !env_editor

User user may run the following commands on this host:
    (ALL) ALL
    (root) NOPASSWD: /home/user/Pidtrk/main.py
    (root) NOPASSWD: /home/user/backdrop.py
```

and again, I am able to run `python2 Pidtrk/main.py` without errors but, not
`python2 backdrop.py`.

And both these files are owned by the same `User` and have the same `Permissions`.

EDIT 2:

I have both of `prog1.py` and `prog2.py` running in a `crontab` on `@reboot`.

If I have this line in `crontab`:

```
`python2 /home/user/prog1.py >> err.log 2>&1`
```

without:

```
user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/user/prog1.py
```

Inside my sudoers file, the err.log shows `it failed with permissions denied`.

Now when I add in this line to sudoers:

```
user ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /home/user/prog1.py
```

The `prog1.py` runs fine on reboot, why is this any different for the `prog2.py` file?

Comment: What are the permissions of `/home/user/prog2.py`? In particular, is it marked executable?

Comment: You should not need to add `rm` to `sudoers`; once you manage to run `prog2.py` as root, all its child processes will inherit the root permissions (unless you take explicit steps to drop privileges; complex scripts should do this in order to minimize the amount of privileged code).

Comment: Wouldn't it be a lot better to have your X session pick up its background image from an unprivileged location instead?

Comment: Better yet use an app: http://vajrasky.wordpress.com/wallpapoz/

Comment: To get the permissions of the file, run `ls -l /home/user/prog2.py` and look at the farthest-left column. Or, post the output of `stat -c '%A %a %u' /home/user/prog2.py; id` here.

Comment: Can you remove the link as root?

Comment: @tijko How do you call the script then? `sudo python2 /home/user/prog2.py`?

Comment: What does "Calling `sudo python2 /home/user/prog2.py` runs as expected" mean? That it succeeds and your problem is solved?

Comment: So what is now the remaining problem then?

Comment: You're not hoping to get this to run as root without saying `sudo`, are you?

Comment: You cannot gain root privileges without using `sudo` (or some other privilege escalation mechanism, such as the `setuid` permission). The `sudoers` file (which is what you edit with `visudo`) is only ever consulted when you invoke the `sudo` command.

Comment: Concerning your second edit: That makes sense to me only if `prog1.py` contains a sudo call to itself.

Comment: @tijko No. I doubt that any Python function calls sudo (or parses sudoers). You can run `python` through `strace -f -e trace=process`. Then you easily see whether sudo is executed.

Comment: @tijko No way can python set the UID to 0 (without having CAP_SETUID or having been UID 0 before). I really hope your `python` is neither installed with SUID root nor with filecaps CAP_SETUID...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in a clarifying comment, you are attempting to run `python2 /home/user/backdrop.py`. But you have granted yourself permission to run a different command -- viz. `/home/user/backdrop.py` without the `python2` -- which you are not allowed to do. `sudo` is very particular about what it allows; either run exactly the command you have the permissions for, or change `sudoers` to allow exactly the command you actually want to run.

Comment: Are you sure it succeeds? My speculation is that Pidtrk either fails silently, or works without `sudo`. But we have yet to see precise, unambiguous examples of what exactly you are doing and how exactly it is failing.

Comment: Now you are saying `python2.7` instead of `python2`...?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that

1. the error is caused within the script
2. the sudo call is correct

then the problem is most probably not sudo. There are several cases in which root is not allowed to remove a file:

1. The file is on a volume which is mounted read-only (see `cat /proc/mounts`).
2. The file is protected by file system attributes (see `lsattr "$path"`).
3. The parent directory is protected by file system attributes.
4. Fancy intervening kernel stuff (SELinux, Apparmor).

It may also be helpful to add a few seconds of waiting time in the script and attach with strace to it (as root): `strace -f -p $PID`

Comment: @tijko If the script waits a moment before it tries its operation you can check with ps as which user it is running.

Comment: @tijko So the problem is still with the sudo call and the sudo configuration. I would expect a sudo error message in that case. Make a test script which just waits and check with `ps -e -o pid,user,euser,suser,args` (to be sure). As tripleee pointed out: It seems that you are inconsistent about your sudoers config and your sudo calls.